# Position Circle at top of box and stay there (responsive)

Tags: css, responsive-design

Can someone please give some guidance on how you would (in a responsive fashion) position a circle over a box, just like in the image below.

What I tried was making the div box relative and a negative px value, but obviously when I shrink down the size, the top of the box is no longer positioned in the middle of the circle.

Can someone please give some guidance as to how you would accomplish this and make it responsive?

[image]

Comment: Will the photo remain the same size, or will it always be a percentage of the containing box? Will there be a minimum size for the photo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best approach to use when both the box and the circle need to be responsive (that is dimensions of both box and circle change with viewport) is to use translate transforms.

Initially position the circle absolutely with respect to the parent at `left: 50%` and `top: 0px` and then use `translateX(-50%)` to move it to left by 50% of the circle's width and `translateY(-50%)` to move it to the top by 50% of the circle's height. Both these together would make the circle retain its position irrespective of whatever their size are.

**Snippet where both circle and box are responsive:**

```css
.box {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 60vh;
  width: 40vh;
  border: 2px solid;
  margin-top: 15vh;
}
.circle {
  position: absolute;
  height: 30vh;
  width: 30vh;
  top: 0px;
  left: 50%;
  border: 2px solid;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: url(http://lorempixel.com/400/400);
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js"></script>
<div class='box'>
  <div class='circle'></div>
</div>
<div class='box'>
  <div class='circle'></div>
</div>
<div class='box'>
  <div class='circle'></div>
</div>
```

**Snippet where only box is responsive:**

```css
.box {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 60vh;
  width: 40vh;
  min-width: 150px;
  min-height: 225px;
  border: 2px solid;
  margin-top: 15vh;
}
.circle {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  top: 0px;
  left: 50%;
  border: 2px solid;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: url(http://lorempixel.com/100/100);
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js"></script>
<div class='box'>
  <div class='circle'></div>
</div>
<div class='box'>
  <div class='circle'></div>
</div>
<div class='box'>
  <div class='circle'></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, this was perfect. Yes, both the circle and box will be responsive and adjust to screen size.